# How to get the returned string in class component (using react-video-thumbnail-image package)

Tags: reactjs, base64

This package can return the base64 string with prop renderThumbnailHtml={false}

```
<VideoImageThumbnail
        videoUrl="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
        thumbnailHandler={(thumbnail) => console.log(thumbnail)}
        width={120}
        height={80}
        alt="my test video"
      />
```

but when I place it into img

```
<img src={`${(
          <VideoImageThumbnail
            videoUrl="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
            thumbnailHandler={(thumbnail) => console.log(thumbnail)}
            renderThumbnailHtml={false}
            width={120}
            height={80}
            alt="my test video"
          />
        )}`}
        alt="test"
      />
```

it just return [Object object] instead of the base64 string.

I stuck on this 3 days already...and don't know what keyword I can google for these kind of issue.

here is the codeSandBox showing the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-joliot-2yqvv6?file=/src/App.js

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use the state variable for your `thumbnail` and update it when the `VideoImageThumbnail` is rendered. Something like this.

```
const [thumbnail, setThumbnail] = useState("");
return (
  <div className="App">
    <h2>DirectOutput</h2>
    <VideoImageThumbnail
      videoUrl="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
      thumbnailHandler={(t) => {
        setThumbnail(t);
      }}
      width={120}
      height={80}
      alt="my test video"
    />
    <h2>Use as an img src</h2>

    <img src={thumbnail} alt="test" />
  </div>
);
```

[image: Edit beautiful-hofstadter-ff3mxp]

Comment: Thanks for reply! it works. but in this case the Thumbnail shows 2 times. How to get rid of it?